# PHP Laravel create and instantiate class

Tags: php, laravel, class

In PHP Laravel I want to create class with properties, class like DTO.
In App\Entity I created class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\DTO;

class UserDTO
{
    public $id;
}
```

And I want to use it in my `Controller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Entity\DTO;

class UserApiController extends Controller
{
    public function loginPost(Request $request)
    {
      ...
      $userDTO = new UserDTO();
      $userDTO->id = $user->id;
    }
}
```

And I have error:

```
Error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\UserDTO' not found in file C:\xampp\htdocs\testsapp\app\Http\Controllers\UserApiController.php on line 131
#0 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\UserApiController->loginPost(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\testsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
```

It's looking for UserDTO in `App\Http\Controllers` nampespace. Don't see `use App\Entity\DTO;`

Comment: Try to replace `use App\Entity\DTO;` to `use App\Entity\DTO\UserDTO;`

Comment: You may want to have a look at [JsonSerializeable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no actual "importing" that happens in PHP, everything is just an alias. You are aliasing `App\Entity\DTO` to `DTO` in this file, so to reference your DTO you would need to use `DTO\UserDTO`:

```
new DTO\UserDTO;
```

You are not importing everything inside `DTO` when you use the statement `use App\Entity\DTO;`; this is the equivalent of `use App\Entity\DTO as DTO;`

You can also just alias this class directly:

```
use App\Entity\DTO\UserDTO;

...

... new UserDTO;
```